# I didn't understand LINE 1 in the skeleton code provided below

Tags: c

```
void fun(struct node* start)
{
    if(start == NULL)
        return;                    // LINE 1
    printf("%d  ", start->data); 

    if(start->next != NULL )
        fun(start->next->next); 
    printf("%d  ", start->data);
}
```

How does that return statement work? I am not getting its working!

The question was:

**What is the output of following function for start pointing to first node of following linked list? 1->2->3->4->5->6**

Comment: What aren't you getting about it?

Comment: It returns tot the caller. That's basic knowledge you can find in your C textbook.

Comment: return is just a way to indicate an exit point from the function.
It must return a value of the functions return-type. In this case - void, which is... nothing...
So the `return` just leaves the function returning nothing. It's the same as placing everything below it in an `else` statement.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement terminates the function immediately; if `start` is `NULL`, the function does nothing. If it is preferred that the function always reaches the end of its body, the function can be rewritten as follows, which some consider more clear.

```
void fun(struct node* start)
{
    if(start != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ", start->data); 

        if(start->next != NULL)
            fun(start->next->next); 
        printf("%d  ", start->data);
    }
}
```

Concerning the output, note that the content of `start->data` is printed *twice*, namely at the beginning and the end of the function's body.

More precisely, consider the following input.

```
1->2->3->4->5->6
```

The first call prints `1` at the end and the beginning and the result of the
following recursive calls in between; the line breaks are for better legibility.

```
1
[output for the list 3->4->5->6]
1
```

Expanding the call in the middle, using the same argument, yields the following output.

```
1
3
[output for the list 5->6]
3
1
```

Again, the recursive call can be expanded.

```
1
3
5
[output for an empty list]
5
3
1
```

As the output for an empty list is also empty, the overall outpur is as follows.

```
1
3
5
5
3
1
```

Comment: I din't get the output of this question. According to my understanding it should print (1,3,5). But the output is (1,3,5,5,3,1).

Answer (score -1):

More specifically, you are seeing the *base case* of a recursive function. A recursive function generally has two branches:

1) The base case (or set of base cases), in which the function simply returns (often with a value, sometimes not).
2) The recursive case, which executes if the base casewhich includes one or more recursive calls to the function itself.

In the function above, the base case is `(start == NULL)`. The recursive case calls `fun(start->next->next);`.